# utf8_encode does not encode special characters ě/š/č/ř/ž/ý/á, etc

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8, encode

I have the following problem which seems to have no solution and I am absolutely disgusted.

I have Android application where users can upload file to my server and then they can access them. So if user opens his account, this application uses function `scandir()` and on my server I use method `json_encode()` to send data to my app to shows him his files and folders. **And here is the problem:**

If some user for example uploads file with special characters (**Válcování stupHovitých vzorko za tepla.pptx**) and this file is not utf-8 encoded, then I can't pass it via json_encode, because I get UTF-8 error. So I tried to use method `uf8_encode()` on each file name and it worked, **BUT** if there is some file or folder with special characters like **č/š/ě/ř/ž/á/ý/í/é, etc.** and use method `utf8_encode()` on it then I get some mess in my application and instead of getting folder with name č, I get name Ä.

I tried nearly everything from `htmlspecialchars()` to `iconv()`, but I can't find a method which returns me files and folders on my server with proper names.

Comment: The utf-8 encoding of 'č' is 'c4 8d'. If you get 'Ä', then it is likely that is *is* utf-8 encoded, but you are not treating it that way. The Unicode for 'Ä' is 'c4'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does not. [The doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) reads:

> utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

Not sure what encoding it is, but it's definitely not [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

You need to use [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert between arbitrary encodings. E.g.

```
$utfStr = mb-convert-encoding('č/š/ě/ř/ž/á/ý/í/é', 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15')
```

If you don't know client's encoding, you may need to use [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php), which may not always work, or be exactly accurate.

To avoid this mess, I would recommend to do it other way round and send utf-encoded file name from your android app, rather than convert it serverside.

Comment: Thank you for answer, sending utf-encoded file name from Android app is good idea, however when I am trying to encode it in my Android app, I still can't get proper file name on my server, I am using this code:
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + fileP + File.separator + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + "\"" + lineEnd);

Instead of getting this file name: Válcování stupňovitých vzorků za tepla.pptx, I am getting this: V%C3%A1lcov%C3%A1n%C3%AD+stup%C5%88ovit%C3%BDch+vzork%C5%AF+za+tepla.pptx

Comment: It is perfectly url-encoded utf8 string. e.g. `%C3%A1` part stands for U+00E1 (hex C3A1) charcter "á".  An http server should url-decode it, and it should appear as a normal utf8 string in PHP. If you get url-encoded string in PHP it is likely you double-url-encode it in your mobile app. I would recommend to fix it there. If it is not feasible, you can just [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it in php.

Comment: Thank you very much! You probably saved my life :)